# How to use Xamarin.Form Controls and Native Controls On the same page

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to use Xamarin.Form Control inside my Native Android Page Controls. In my Android native page is there any way to load a Xamarin.Form Page inside my Native Android Fragment or LinearLayout?

According to [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/forms) it's possible. But I cannot find how to achieve this.

[image: http://xamarin.com/forms]

Comment: There is a way to hack this in, in case anyone still needs to. Very much a hack, involving decompilation and copying several classes from the very Xamarin.Forms framework, was developed by my colleague, and described [in his blog post](http://www.arturdr.ru/android/xamarin-forms-i-slozhnosti-integratsii-v-android-prilozheniya/). The post is, unfortunately, in Russian, but is pretty google-translatable, and you don't need to read anything to copy the code or download the sample (see a .zip below code).

Comment: One caveat is to always .Dispose() views you get from the hacked inflater - memory management is normally done by Xamarin.Forms, and does not work on its own outside.

Comment: Is this still not possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a few things being discussed, so bear with me:

The image snippet, from what I understand:

```
 "Not only are Xamarin.Forms pages mixable with custom screens" ...
```

This is like what @Stephane is mentioning allowing an application to use native screens **as well** as **Xamarin.Forms** screens.  Each *platform* *stub-page* can introduce a shared **Xamarin.Forms** page at any point in the application.  You don't have to use the **Xamarin.Forms** **Navigation Stack**.

```
 "but you can embed custom views built directly against Xamarin.IOS and Xamarin.Android into Xamarin.Forms pages."
```

This is what @Sten is mentioning, where if you create **platform specific** **ContentRenderers** you can render any kind of *native controls* **into an existing** **Xamarin.Forms** page, by passing this common **View** to each platform renderer.

So, for instance if you had a **View**:-

```
 public class MyView : ContentView
 {
     // Create some bindable properties here that can be used in your platform specific renderer,
     // i.e. DisplayText etc.
 }
```

You can use the above in a **Xamarin.Forms** page definition and then create *platform specific renderers* that would be called to *render the content*.

It is from within these *platform specific content renderer classes* that you can use *native controls* on each platform.

For instance in the **ContentRenderer**, for the event **OnElementChanged** you could do something like the following for **WindowsPhone**:-

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinPhone.ElementChangedEventArgs<MyView> e)
 {
     base.onElementChanged(e);
     ...
     System.Windows.Controls.TextBox objPlatformSpecificTextBox = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();
     ... 
     ...
```

However, what @Gulshan is really wanting I believe is to have a **native page** that is **center-stage** with the **Xamarin.Forms** content being rendered **into a specific point** in an *already existing native page*.

Its kinda-reversed, in thinking, however this is still possible:-

To achieve this you need to stimulate page-generation into a **temporary new page**.

For instance in **WindowsPhone** you would do this via:-

```
        PhoneApplicationPage objInnerPage_Temp = new PhoneApplicationPage();
        UIElement objInnerContent = App.GetMainPage().ConvertPageToUIElement(objInnerPage_Temp);
```

on the **platform specific stub-page**.

You can then **inject** the rendered contents into a **native container** that is appropriate on the platform, i.e. a **Grid**.

**Update 1:-**

**==========**

Although its very easy to do this on **WindowsPhone** it doesn't seem that this is possible when attempting something similar in **Android** unfortunately.

The **Android** page creation is very locked down, i.e. you **can't** gain access to the **private** fields for **canvas** and/or **layout** that it internally uses in **AndroidActivity**.

If this was possible then you could re-use this and take the contents rendered and **inject** similar to the solution  for the **WindowsPhone** platform.

Furthermore, the **Platform** class is flagged as **internal** also, preventing another way to generate the rendered contents.

There was hope I was thinking from approaching this from a **Fragment** implementation of generating an **Activity** into it, and this could well work - *However* - the issue here is that the implementation in **Xamarin.Forms** is expecting the **ActionBar** to be available of which it is not, and they aren't checking for a *if null* scenario to allow execution to continue if it is not available so it throws an exception preventing page content generation.

It doesn't therefore look possible?, unless they open up the layout / canvas fields in **AndroidActivity** or address the *ActionBar* expectation issue.

Comment: Yes I am aware of custom renderer. But using a renderer, I think I can only achieve using a native controls inside a Xamarin.Forms Page. But my requirement is totally opposite. I want to use xamarin.Forms Page inside some Native Controls. If you look at the Activity where a Xamarin.Forms page has been used, There is a method "SetContentPage()" Which takes a XamarinForms Page as an input set it to the whole activity. What I am looking for is, A way where I can set my XamarinForm Page or Control inside a Layout or Fragement. Or if I can convert Xamarin.Forms.View to Android.Views.View.

Comment: The last part of my answer did highlight what I believed your real intention was and suggested an approach.  Its possible via **WindowsPhone** easily, however **Android** is very locked down.  I've updated my answer to reflect new findings (see *Update 1*).  Where are you seeing *SetContentPage()* for *Android* as I don't appear to be able to find this method?

Comment: Yes very much true. I was actually looking for a similar method in android like "ConvertPageToUIElement" in Windows Phone. I have extracted the code of AndroidActivity. And you are right the Platform class is marked as internal. So may be for now it's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

As already discussed it is fairly simple on **iOS** (with *.CreateViewController()*) and **WP** (*.ConvertPageToUIElement()*).

But on **Android** all is not lost too: you can use **.GetView() extension** method from http://www.arturdr.ru/android/xamarin-forms-i-slozhnosti-integratsii-v-android-prilozheniya/

Here is an example on how to wrap Xamarin.Forms page in Android AlertDialog using that method:
https://github.com/OlexaLe/XFPageAsAndroidDialog

Comment: Unfortunately, significant changes would be required to update that code to work with current Xamarin Forms. I've added an issue to XFPageAsAndroidDialog project, briefly describing what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for a custom renderer.

- In your Forms project create a class MyView that inherits from `View` (or some other suitable class, say ContentView if you'll have child views etc)
- In your Android project create a renderer class MyViewRenderer that inherits `ViewRenderer`
- Add the attribute to that class that indicates it's a renderer *before* the namespace declaration
  `[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(MyView), typeof(MyViewRenderer))]`
- In MyViewRenderer override OnElementChanged, call `base.SetNativeView(ctl)` where ctl is an instance of your native control

Take a look at [Xamarin's guide](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/)

Another resource in [Xamarin's Forums](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18381/seeking-rounded-corners-recipie-for-xamarin-forms-have-one-for-monotouch).

After looking at the issue and implementing my own Border I'd say `VisualElementRenderer<TElement>` is a better renderer to use. If you use that all you'd need to do is override OnElementChanged and do `NativeView.Add(customUIView)` and copy properties from the MyView instance. To handle dynamic changes in these properties override OnElementPropertyChanged and update the customUIView instance

Comment: Yes I am aware of custom renderer. But using a renderer, I think I can only achieve using a native controls inside a Xamarin.Forms Page. But my requirement is totally opposite. I want to use xamarin.Forms Page inside some Native Controls. If you look at the Activity where a Xamarin.Forms page has been used, There is a method "SetContentPage()" Which takes a XamarinForms Page as an input set it to the whole activity. What I am looking for is, A way where I can set my XamarinForm Page or Control inside a Layout or Fragement. Or if I can convert Xamarin.Forms.View to Android.Views.View.

Comment: how about a Forms Page that holds the native control in a custom renderer and a NativeChild custom renderer that can move its view as a subview of the native? I don't think it's possible to achieve this in a completely native app

Comment: Its possible in **WindowsPhone**, however **Android** is too locked down it appears.  I haven't tested this on **iOS** at present.

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin revised its website, so the image above is outdated. As the Xamarin.Forms library has evolved, it appears that it became tougher to mix Xamarin.Forms and platform-specific native views. I would not recommend doing this.

Advanced users can certainly attempt this, but my conversations with other developers suggest that this creates a lot of extra work and overhead. The best path forward is to either use Xamarin.Forms exclusively for your views, or use platform-specific native views.

Here's a screenshot from Xamarin's Xamarin.Forms page (shot taken on May 13, 2015):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `Activity` that is backed by `Xamarin.Forms` by inheriting from `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AndroidActivity` and launch this new activity from another one in your Xamarin.Android application.

Comment: Yes I know that. The problem is Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AndroidActivity has only one Method SetPage(Xamarin.Forms.Page page) which shows the Xamarin.Forms Page in full screen. What I want is, on my Activity I have lot of other native Android Controls. And In between those Controls I want to use my one Xamarin.Forms Page or View.